# ExtJS: ajax call on keystroke not working while another call is existant

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

So I have a situation where there is an ajax call made after a keystroke (with `buffer:150`). If (for whatever reason) the ajax call is slightly laggy to return, keypress during that load process fail to make another call.

The component is a tree using a loader for the data. And is setup as follows:

**tree config**

```
....
root:{
    nodeType:'async',
    text:'Accounts',
    expanded:false,
    uiProvider:false
},
loader: {
    dataUrl:'dataurl',
    baseParams:{},
    loadexception:function(){
        console.log('Failed to load QUICKSEARCH');
    }
}
....
```

with the following on a text field

**textfield listener**

```
....
listeners:{
keyup:{buffer:150, fn:function(f, e) {
    if(Ext.EventObject.ESC == e.getKey()) {
        field.onTriggerClick();
    }else{
    var val = this.getRawValue();
            thisTree = this.ownerCt.ownerCt;
            thisTree.loader.baseParams.quicksearch_string = val;
            thisTree.root.reload();
    }
}}
}
....
```

Ideally, I want to be able to cancel (either completely cancel, or cancel listening for the response) the call and start the new one.

So I guess there should actually be a question in here somewhere...So is there a way to cancel listening for a previously made ajax call or a setting to force a newer call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an alternative way of reloading the tree. Here is another syntax I have seen.

```
thisTree.getLoader().load(thisTree.root);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here what your looking for is asynchronous ajax calls.

This is possible, although it is important to remember that these calls will not necessarily return in any given order, so it is only acceptable to use these when the order of return does not matter. (Although, you can work around this, it will get complicated).

In order to accomplish this (dynamically) you should have a function which uses a series of incremental iframes, and thus the algorithm is the following:

If(document.getElementById('iframe1').isDone()){
   iframe1.src = newSrc
}else{
  iframe2.src = newSrc
}

These will BOTH be able to run and return asynchronously. This functionality can also be put into a dynamic loop, allowing any number of asynchronous iframe calls, but you'll have to use google for that!

Comment: Isnt AJAX - Asynchronous Javascript and XML? The problem isnt the fact they wont run together. I can make many ajax calls at once. The issue is im "reloading" the store on keystroke, but the "loader" wont fire the next call until the orevious one returns. I believe it is an issue with the ExtJS Component, rather than the...errr, synchronicity (is that a word?) of the calls. ajax IS asynchronous. But thanks for the answer

Comment: Why not have ajax make a direct callback to a function rather then have a listener?

Comment: sorry, but I dont understand what you are saying... The listener is on keystrokes of a text field, so that after the user presses a key, I want the loader updated (after a buffer period)